# Splicing an object from array in angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm struggling to get my head around how to delete a single object from my array from inside a directive...

In my controller I ng-repeat over my object to give me a category header followed by the children of that category. Eg,

```
{
deptName: 'Fruit',
deptProducts: [{
    name: 'Mangos',
    price: '50p'
    },{
    name: 'Apples',
    price: '30p',
    },{
    name: 'Grapes',
    price: '20p',
    },{
    name: 'Bananas',
    price: '10p',
    }]
}
```

My ng-repeat contains the group name and a directive for each item.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in shopping">
    <span ng-bind="item.deptName"></span>
    <product ng-repeat="prod in item.deptProducts />
</div>
```

And in the template function in my directive i have a button with ng-click which i want to delete one of the items in the object, so

```
function product() {
    return {
    scope: true,
    template: '<span ng-bind="prod.price"></span><button ng-click="removeItem()"></button>
    }
}
```

I'm not sure as to how best to call the function to splice the node so that the model is updated. Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass the array to the directive, I hope this code can help you.

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('test', function ($scope) {
    $scope.item = {
      deptName: 'Fruit',
      deptProducts: [{
        name: 'Mangos',
        price: '50p'
        },{
        name: 'Apples',
        price: '30p',
        },{
        name: 'Grapes',
        price: '20p',
        },{
        name: 'Bananas',
        price: '10p',
        }]
    };
  })
  .directive('product', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: {
        index: '@',
        products: '=',
      },
      template: '<span ng-bind="products[index].price"></span><button ng-click="products.splice(index, 1)">Remove</button>',
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
  <div>
      <div ng-bind="item.deptName"></div>
      <product ng-repeat="prod in item.deptProducts" index="{{$index}}" products="item.deptProducts"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I liked this approach, it's very easy to follow. I called a function to do the splice, but other than that this answer was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

You would need access to the `deptProducts` array inside of the directive in order to actually manipulate it. It would be simpler to set a property that allows the product to display or not:

```
return {
  scope: {product: "="},
  template: '<span>{{prod.price}}</span><button ng-click="prod.remove= false"></button>
}
```

Then you can use `ng-if="!prod.remove"`

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options. One is to pass in the collection of products to the directive and do the removing inside the directive. The other is to create a function on the controller that removes the product and then pass that function into the directive and call it from within the directive. The issue with the latter is that you'd have to pass enough information back to the controller for it to figure out which item in which collection you actually want to remove. Here is a sample that shows both approaches, although I only show how to call a method on the controller and pass a parameter to it since the rest of it is not trivial.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.shopping = [{
      deptName: 'Fruit',
      deptProducts: [{
        name: 'Mangos',
        price: '50p'
      }, {
        name: 'Apples',
        price: '30p',
      }, {
        name: 'Grapes',
        price: '20p',
      }, {
        name: 'Bananas',
        price: '10p',
      }]
    }];
    $scope.remove = function(prod) {
      console.log('remove in ctrl', prod);
    };
  })
  .directive('product', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        products: '=',
        index: '=',
        removeFunction: '&'
      },
      template: '<div><span ng-bind="products[index].name"></span><span ng-bind="products[index].price"></span><button ng-click="removeItem()">Remove</button><span></div>',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        scope.removeItem = function() {
          scope.removeFunction({
            prod: scope.products[scope.index]
          });
          scope.products.splice(scope.index, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in shopping">
    <span ng-bind="item.deptName"></span>
    <product ng-repeat="prod in item.deptProducts" products="item.deptProducts" index="$index" remove-function="remove(prod)" />
  </div>
</div>
```